# Overriding a Local Variable name in Java Bytecode using the ASM library

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I read a class' methods and their contents using the ASM library for Java ByteCode. This is to output any method's local variables names in the class:

```
ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(new FileInputStream(new File("TheClass.class")));

final ClassNode classNode = new ClassNode();
reader.accept(classNode, 0);

for (final MethodNode mn : (List<MethodNode>)classNode.methods) {
    for (LocalVariableNode n : (List<LocalVariableNode>)mn.localVariables) {
        System.out.println(n.name);
    }
}
```

And this is the source of the compiled `TheClass` class file:

```
public class TheClass {
    public final String a;
    public final String b;

    public TheClass(String c, String d) {
        this.b = d;
        this.a = c;
    }
}
```

So the output is, logically, `this`, `c`, `d`. **Now, I need to copy this compiled class into a new file, but change the `<init>` method's parameters (local variables) to different names (`e`, `f`). How can I do so?** I have little to no experience with MethodVisitors and such.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? The only use of local variable names is for debugging and reflection.

Comment: @Antimony the example provided here is just an example. The ultimate goal to this is to assign names to different local variables in methods which do not already have a name. For example, a method could have 9 different local variables inside of it, but with all the same "name" attribute (this is possible in bytecode), and the goal is to assign a different name to each of them (var1, var2, ...). Ultimately, the class itself will get decompiled with different local variable names.

Comment: Why not add names during the decompilation process? That's what I'd do. Not all decompilers even use the LocalVariableTable information in the first place.

Comment: If all you want to do is to aid a decompiler which stumbles over a misleading local variable table, the easiest solution is to remove this debugging information completely. Then, the decompiler is forced to generate names for the local variables and won’t try to use the nonsensical names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to write an adapter (a subclass of `ClassVisitor`) and chain it with `reader`. For instance,

```
ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(new FileInputStream(new File("TheClass")));
ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(reader, 0);
TraceClassVisitor printer = new TraceClassVisitor(writer, 
    new PrintWriter(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") 
            + File.separator + name + ".log"));
ClassAdapter adapter = new ClassAdapter(printer);
reader.accept(adapter, 0);
byte[] b = writer.toByteArray();
```

With it you'll get `byte[]`, which you can save into file, or load into `Class` with a [`ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html).

(`TraceClassVisitor` is just another `ClassVisitor` that I chain it also to get a human-readable log in your temp directory.)

The adapter could look like the following. The method you'll want to override is [`visitLocalVariable`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/index.html):

```
public class ClassAdapter extends ClassVisitor {
    public ClassAdapter(ClassVisitor cv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, cv);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
            String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
        return new MethodAdapter(mv);
    }
}

public class MethodAdapter extends MethodVisitor {
    public MethodAdapter(MethodVisitor mv) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, mv);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitLocalVariable(String name, String desc, String signature,
            Label start, Label end, int index) {
        // Put your rename logic here
        if (name.equals("c"))
            name = "e";
        else if (name.equals("d"))
            name = "f";
        super.visitLocalVariable(name, desc, signature, start, end, index);
    }
}
```